# How to Install Composer globally on Cloudlinux

Tags: linux, installation, cloud, composer-php

I can't seem to install Composer globally on Cloudlinux.
I have managed to install packages like git etc but these are actual packages unlike composer.

I made Git globally available using the cagefsctl e.g.:

```
$ cagefsctl --addrpm git
$ cagefsctl --update
```

But this doesn't seem to work for Composer (which makes sense).

How do I do this for non packages like Composer?

Comment: I'd say you should run the command line like everyone else, as mentioned on the Composer documentation page. You can also just download that `.phar` file yourself and place it somewhere like `/usr/local/bin` if that's in the path, and make it eXecutable with `chmod`.

Comment: I've installed it using the documentation on composer's website but it's only accessible via root, other users just get "command not found".

Comment: Then these users don't have the file location in their shell path. You have to configure this.

Comment: Do you know of a way to automatically add this path to all new users? getting of topic but it will answer my question.

Comment: There are central configurations like `/etc/.profile` or `/etc/bashrc` that are included before any user specific configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install composer, you must first download and install the package :

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Once the package is install move the file :

```
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

If you are using CageFS, you'll need to take a extra step and create a configuration file for Composer using vim :

```
vi  /etc/cagefs/conf.d/composer.cfg
```

In the file, you'll need to declare the composer executable :

```
[composer]
paths = /usr/local/bin/composer
```